# What is Best Practice when storing MacBooks for over a month?

Tags: hardware, battery, macbook-pro

We have a pod of 30 MacBooks and MacBook Pros that don't get used over the holidays.

What's best practice to store the laptops for 6 weeks? I know that when you store laptops for long periods at half charge, unplugged in a cool place is a good idea, but in practice I've just put them plugged-in in the storeroom! Could anyone share their best practice methods when storing these sort of devices?

Comment: You could look at this discussion http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2525736&tstart=0

Comment: *Pod of MacBooks*.... sounds like some kind of horror film that would make Steve Ballmer scream like a little girl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I think Apple suggests when you need to store you MacBook for longer periods:

- discharge your battery to 50% and keep the laptop in a cool place
- if you plan to not use the computer for more than 5 months take the battery off the laptop
- you will probably need to charge the battery every 6 months to better preserve it.

Answer (score 1):

Power it down and make sure it's somewhere where there is no chance of it getting wet.